# Link pictures to existing documents in document library

Tags: document-set, attachments

In the current setup I'm working on I have a quite big challenge.

I have a document set with some pdf documents inside. Each pdf document has a kind of identifier (problemID metadata field for example). Now I want a way to attach images to this PDF file  in a kind of way. I know when you're using a list, you can add the 'attachments' column, but it isn't possible on documents in a document library. Is there any workaround or maybe other solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't you have a new column of type link in the library?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. The problem is 1 document should contain multiple images/links. So I have 1 problem document (the pdf) and multiple images attached to it.

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a New List with a LookUp Column ParentID linked to Document Library's ID column and another column Image/HyperLink Column.

In this Way you can have multiple imaged attached to a single document.

Another way is to create a custom field type which could hold different images.
For details on how to create custom field check this [link](http://christopherclementen.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/create-custom-field-type-with-user-control/).

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves your query

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I will try it out as soon as possible. For usablity I think I'll follow the second solution by creating a custom field type. Do you have any experience with this and/or is it reliable?

Comment: Thanks is nothing without an UpVote :) .It's reliable.A good knowledge is required. No i have not created a similar kind of solution. You can google for same and will get numerous examples to create such a field.